# Problem with Jmeter certificate to record a test

Tags: jmeter, certificate

I'm trying to record a test, but when I install my certificate by Jmeter in the chrome, when I access the site that I want to record, chrome return me this:

[image: Chrome recording certificate error]

But my certificate that I installed before access the site is 100% valid:

[image: Windows certificates]

Other points:

- I already made the Jmeter HTTPS proxy route configuration;
- I already made the Windows/Browser proxy route configuration;
- I installed the certificate correctly.

I don't know why my browser is not looking for the valid certificate and even without any certificate installed, still looks to this invalid certificate

Answer (score 1):

If this is blocking you please install the certificate on Firefox and proceed with recording after setting the proxy.

> 1. Open Firefox
> 2. Type about:prefrences in the address bar
> 3. Search for certificates in search box
> 4. Click on View Certificate button
> 5. Select Authorities tab
> 6. Click on Import button
> 7. Select the certificate from your JMeter/bin folder
> 8. Check the first option in the popup (Trust CA to identify the websites)
> 9. Click OK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome warns you because JMeter's certificate is [self-signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) and it cannot be validated against [trusted CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)

The options are in:

1. Ignore this error, the options are in:

   - Click "Proceed to unsafe" (if it's available)

     [image]
   - Launch Chrome with [`--ignore-certificate-errors` command-line argument](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227989087-Chrome-for-Windows-only-HSTS-Certificate-Exception-Instructions):
   - type [`badidea`](https://twilblog.github.io/chrome/security/2016/06/27/badidea.html) anywhere at the page
2. Add [JMeter's self-signed certificate to Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/):

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Mac OSX instructions for this were nowhere to be found.

On a Mac, just import "the root cert" from the Jmeter `bin` directory and into your "Keychain Access" tool.   If you have to, you can use a tool called "Keystore Explorer" to convert the `.crt` file to a `.cer` before you do that import.

Then, you have to mark the cert trusted like this:

[image]